# Parse Json Data by javascript or Jquery on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse data on client side, I am keeping data in input field after serialization.

```
JavaScriptSerializer objJavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonString = objJavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(_statusVal);
jsonFmtStatusValue.Value = jsonString;
```

**On Client Side When I saw the data string which is stored in input field it's coming like this**

```
[
    {
        "nodeContentId": "1234_5678",
        "statusTypeId": "5678",
        "statusName": "Submitted by Customer",
        "dateTime": "/Date(1352745000000)/",
        "forceEmail": "on",
        "user": {
            "userId": "0",
            "userName": "admin"
        },
        "note": {
            "typeName": null,
            "dataValue": null
        }
    },
    {
        "nodeContentId": "1234_5678",
        "statusTypeId": "5678",
        "statusName": "Checked, Printed, Folded & Re-checked",
        "dateTime": "/Date(1353402060000)/",
        "forceEmail": "on",
        "user": {
            "userId": "0",
            "userName": "admin"
        },
        "note": {
            "typeName": null,
            "dataValue": null
        }
    }
]
```

Code Which I tried to parse Json data is :

```
    var JsonData = $("#<%=jsonFmtStatusValue.ClientID %>").val();
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JsonData)
    alert(obj.nodeContentId);
```

Things I get in alert box: 
**Undefine**

Not able to figure out what should i use for parsing.

Comment: @pst: He quoted his code doing the parsing, that part's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Note: I'm assuming that `jsonFmtStatusValue` ends up being an `input` or `textarea` on the page.)*

In your `alert(obj.nodeContentId);`, `obj` is the *array*, not an object *in* the array. Your outermost JSON entity is an array, which then contains objects.

You can see the *first* `nodeContentId` like this:

```
alert(obj[0].nodeContentId);
```

...and of course the others are at subsequent indexes, so for instance:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JsonData);
var n;
for (n = 0; n < obj.length; ++n) {
    alert("obj[" + n + "].nodeContentId = " + obj[n].nodeContentId);
}
```